# why database connection is failed when i am trying to running jar file of my java application and i am using a 'Derby' Embedded database

Tags: database, derby

so i made a project with MYSQl database but because of the embedded facility of 'Derby' i switched to Derby database. I uesd Netbeans IDE  in which my application is work perfectly (all operation  are performed very well) but when i make a jar file of my application and run it then its stucked at a point where its need to fetch the data from database, I think that this jar file is unable to connect the database when i run it. my project is simple java project not maven proj.
I have no idea what to do and i am new to derby database please help me to complete my project!

I am mentioning some images

[Connection Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyeid.png)
[Connection code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaY24.png)

[Derby libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O32Jb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer we need to add 3 jar file  in libraries

1. `Derby.jar`
2. `DerbyShared.jar`
3. `Derbytools.jar`

These are Embedded database Drivers of Derby not for Server.